# Calculating Time Complexity(input divisible by 2)

Tags: performance, algorithm, time, complexity-theory

How would I calculate the time complexity or T(n) of this section of code?

```
j=1;
while(j<=n/2){
   i=1;
   while(i<=j){
      cout<<j<<i;
      i++;
   }
   j++
}
```

I think you can assume that n is divisible by 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not hard to count the total number of iterations. The range for j is j=1, 2, ..., n/2. For each value of j, the range for i is i = 1, 2, ..., j. So, there are j iterations of the inner loop for each value of the outer loop. This means that the total number of iterations is:

T(n) = 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n/2 = (1/2)(n/2)(n/2+1) = (1/8)(n^2 + 2n).

[Note: I am using the identity 1 + 2 + ... + k = k(k+1)/2 here.]

This function is, as has been stated, O(n^2).

Answer (score 4):

Dividing by a constant does not change the `O(...)`. Exact divisibility does not matter either. Just like the algorithm where `j` goes all the way up to `n`, this is an `O(N^2)` algorithm.

Comment: Would this effect T(n) though?

Comment: @blakepeterman Do you mean division by constant? No, it wouldn't: a loop that goes half (or one tenth, whatever) of the full length of the list is `O(n)`, unless the divisor depends on `n` (in which case it's no longer a constant).

Comment: This question is specifically asking about T(n) though, which generally refers to a specific time function (number of operations for input size n). It is typically an educational step leading up to talking about O(T(n)).

Answer (score 2):

```
while(j<=n/2){            |      n/2+1
   i=1;                   |      n/2
   while(i<=j){           |      1+n/2(n/2+1)/2 =1+n(n+1)/8
      cout<<j<<i;         |      n(n+1)/8
      i++;                |      n(n+1)/8
   }                      |
   j++                    |      n/2
}                         |
```

Overall : O(n<sup>2</sup>)